# CSS - Absolute position , how to ignore left and top of parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

Maybe this question is crazy, I would like to know if there is a way to have an element with css position:absolute that jumps one parent and respect parent's parent left and top.

```
 <div id='parentParent' style="position:absolute;left: 0 ;top: 0;" >
     <div id='parent' style="position:absolute;left :50% ; top:50%" >
          <canvas id='myElement' style="position:absolute" ></canvas>
     </div>
 </div>
```

In this case, I need to have myElement inside parent div, but I can't change parent left and top, so I would like to avoid parent's left=50% and top = 50% and has myElement to use left=0 and top=0 but as it is absolute I think it takes parent's left and top. How can I achieve it? preserving this nesting order.

Sorry if this doesn't makes sense or is stupid, but I would like to know if there is a way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The position of a child is based on the position of the nearest positioned parent. So if you can't remove the positioning on the parent, you'll have to find another solution. Perhaps you could use `top: 0; left: 0` and then use transforms on `myElement` to move it further.

Comment: you can make the `parentParent` as the parent of your `myElement` by adding `position:relative` to it, while the `parent` **should not** have `position` set to any one of `relative` or `fixed` or `absolute`. The rule of determining the parent of an absolute element is different.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for your comment. Would you have a sample of using transforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the parent -> parent to relative.  the absolute should respect that as it's starting point so long as the immediate parent is not set to relative as well.

Answer (score -1):

You could always traverse using javascript and set the top?

Get parentParent offset top and the parents top and calculate the position relative to the difference?

Why out of interest do you need to nest the canvas element? can it not just live in the parentParent if it is being positioned absolutely anyway?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, I need to have it inside parent, if I move it inside parentParent it affect other functionalities.
Would you have a sample with JS?